# Xpath поиск по вхождению строки в атрибуте элемента, как?

Tags: xpath, simplexml

Имеем такое `XPath` выражение, которое выбирает только один узел.

```
"/tns:xfdf/tns:fields/tns:field[@name='comments1']"
```

В `XML` присутствуют узлы с атрибутом `name=comments1, name=comments2, name=comments3` и так далее.

Как одним `XPath` выражением выбрать все элементы с вхождением слова comments в значении атрибута?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался сам.

```
"/tns:xfdf/tns:fields/tns:field[contains(@name, 'comments')]"
```